# Unable to display tiff images in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have images that I'm displaying on my React app.
I have no problem displaying images that are jpeg, png etc...
I have a problem displaying images that are tif, tiff.
I also saw that only Safari supports it out of the box. Is there a workaround to displaying a tif/tiff?

CLICK HERE -> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/array-formik-c0dg3?file=/src/components/MediaCard/index.js:252-263)

```
    <img
      style={{
        display: isImageLoaded ? "flex" : "none",
        width: "100%",
        cursor: "zoom-in"
      }}
      src={productImage.imageUrl}
      alt="fef"
      onLoad={handleImageLoading}
    />

    {!isImageLoaded && <CircularProgress />}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still no support for Firefox, Chrome and many other browsers

This chart confirms

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

If you want to use those browsers you will have to convert your images.

Comment: Another source, confirming this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types